# Golang sFTP SSH : Authentification Failed

Tags: go

For 3 days, I have been trying to set up a sFTP connection to upload a file to a client server.

I'm using this :
https://gist.github.com/svett/b7f56afc966a6b6ac2fc

Only difference being that I added :

```
sshConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User: "0000003579",
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
        //SSHAgent(),
        PublicKeyFile("C:\\GoDev\\src\\Texel.ca\\Bnc_Ftp\\.ssh\\id_rsa"),
    },
    HostKeyCallback:   ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    HostKeyAlgorithms: []string{"ssh-dss"},
}
sshConfig.Ciphers = append(sshConfig.Ciphers, "aes128-cbc")
```

because my client server still use cbc and still use ssh-dss.

**My issue :**

When trying to connect, I get the following response:

> Failed to dial: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain

I tried to connect with the same credential via openSSH in a command line

```
ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss ***@2XXX.XXX.XXX.XX -vvv
```

and it works.

Can I get more infos on my error like the -vvv command with openSSH? Or do any of you have an idea?

Thank you!

EDIT

Just for more information, there is a working tool right now that does the sftp transfert and it works.

But it's a .bat file that's why we are changing it to go.

It use WinSCP to connect to the sFTP with a rsa putty private key.

That might be one of the issue, as if I understand correctly, I can't use a puTTy private key with golang ssh package.

So I tried both the putty key and a conversion to openSSH, but both won't work.

Comment: Can you check the logs on the server? It appears to be the authentication that's failing (if it was the HostKeyAlgorithm or Ciphers list, you would get a "no common algorithm" error)

Comment: Sadly, I don't have access to the server. They have a really slow service and trying to get them to check something take weeks. 

Can't I get the logs on the client side? Like with openSSH in a terminal, I seem to have have a lot more info as a client.

Comment: Are you using that linked example exactly as written? It's swallowing errors silently, so I would start by fixing the code there and adding some logging. Otherwise, you can go into the ssh package and change `debugHandshake`  to true to get some more into, or start adding your own debug logging.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, I will try it.

Also I tried to debug it manually in the ssh package. I get all the way to client_auth in the confirmKeyAck function, where the function readPacket the data.

it detect a msgUserAuthFailure, but I can't seems to read anything in it. I tried to unmarshall it with Unmarshal(packet, &msg);  but when I print msg I get a nil value.

I'm new to GO so I might no do it right.

Answer (score 0):

With openssh you're *adding* dss to the algorithms, and are using an unknown key. This key will be your default for the user and probably not the one you're using on the go side?

On the Go side you're using *only* the dss Algorithm and an rsa key, which might be the problem?

Make sure you're using the same key and same algorithms in both cases and that the algorithm matches the key.

If still stuck perhaps post the full output of -vvv and *all* the errors on the go side.

Comment: My knowledge in SSH is a bit lacking. :)

I tried without the HostKeyAlgorithms before, but it wouldnt work ether.

I will add an edit for more informations on the main post. See the edit about the private key.

Also, can I use -vvv to output the error on the go side?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I would suspect the keys. I can't see how it would work as you're asking it to use dss (dsa key), but using an rsa key. You should try openssh with the key you have here specified via the -i option so you're sure your'e testing the same key, or try a different dsa key on the go side (if as you say the server only uses dss). On go side no -vvv will do nothing, follow the instructions above from jimb.

Comment: Also try openssl using only ssh-dss and see if your assumption is correct that this should be the algorithm used.